# Chrome: Cannot Use Tab Key

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am testing few javascript examples in chrome console where I need to write a function. Problem is I am unable to use TAB key to move line to right 2 spaces inside a function like

```
function abc(){
  //Need to use tab to properly format
};
```

Anyone Please.

Comment: If you're trying to test javascript functions, I suggest to use a file or jsfiddle.net as soon as it is more than one line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to the [Official Doc](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/shortcuts) it's not possible.

You will have to use spaces, write your code in other editors an then copy it, or use Firefox ...

For fun : [Spaces VS Tabs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/04/death-to-the-space-infidels.html)

Answer (score -1):

that is the correct behaviour, JavaScript works just as well without tabs and equally without carriage returns.